# Recurring Payment using PayPal Advanced

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

In my asp.net MVC application i have a recurring payment section. I have implemented the recurring payment section using web payments standards.  I have followed the same way as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723390/paypal-recurring-payment-transaction-error-11502-token-is-invalid). Now my client asked me to implement the same via Paypal advanced so that the user could do most of the Paypal operation without redirecting to PayPal site and also they could using Credit Card payment too.

I have looked for a good article on how to implement recurring payment using PayPal advanced but i couldn't get a proper documentation for the same. I could find an options named "Enhanced Recurring Payments for PayPal Payments Standard" to implement recurring payment in PayPal advance. But couldn't find a good article regarding the same.

Do anyone has a article or idea on implementing the recurring transaction using PayPal advance. Does this can be implemented via sandbox testing?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513505/paypal-advanced-payment-and-payflow-link-with-reccuring-payments/18523422#18523422 .