# Paypal Advanced Payment and PayFlow Link with Reccuring Payments

Tags: java, paypal, payment

We want to implement Paypal in our application. This is what we need:

- reccuring payments,
- trial period,
- coupon codes,
- payment without leave our page,

We found that we can use for it Paypal Advanced Payment and PayFlow Link (Gateway Developer Guide and Reference), but on 30 site of this document link only to PayFlow Pro. We found information that difference beetwen Pro and Link version in only that we can do modification to template view on page templetes.

- Can we use reccuring payments with Paypal Advanced Payment and PayFlow Link?
- If yes? How? Links to developers guides would be usefull,
- Which products should we use to meet our needs?

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although you have to do it in something of a roundabout way when you're using PayPal Payments Advanced/Payflow Link.

If your buyer is going to use a credit card to pay for the profile, you'll need to run a transaction first, grab the PNREF of the transaction, then use that to create the recurring billing profile.  Chapter 2 of the Payflow Gateway guide (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf) should help you figure out how to run the initial transaction; the Recurring Billing Service Guide should help you with setting up the recurring billing profile (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf -- there are specific examples on page 16, under "Converting an Existing Transaction Into a Profile").

If your buyer is going to pay with PayPal (which is a real possibility when you use PayPal Payments Advanced or Payflow Link), you'll need to run a transaction, get them to sign up for a billing agreement at the same time, then use the billing agreement to create the recurring billing profile.  When you set up your transaction (Chapter 2 of the Payflow Gateway guide, same link as above), pass `BILLINGTYPE=MerchantInitiatedBilling` (piece of advice -- you need to get approved by PayPal before you do this).  When the buyer completes the payment, PayPal will give you a BAID back -- pass the BAID in when creating the recurring billing profile.  (Again, the Recurring Billing Service Guide has examples of this, on page 16, under "Adding a New Profile for a PayPal Account".)